# Unable to build Scala Maven project

Tags: scala, maven

I am trying to build a maven-scala project. After creating the project, I created "clean compile" to build the project. When I run the build option, I see the below exception message:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\ABCSparkWorkSpace\DataExpo "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=54199:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.1.4 clean compile

[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.dbloads.programs:DataExpo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin is missing. @ line 51, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin is missing. @ line 69, column 15
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DataExpo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ DataExpo ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\ABCSparkWorkSpace\DataExpo\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ DataExpo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\ABCSparkWorkSpace\DataExpo\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ DataExpo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) @ DataExpo ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] C:\ABCSparkWorkSpace\DataExpo\src\main\scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to C:\ABCSparkWorkSpace\DataExpo\target\classes at 1528970864912
[ERROR] error: error while loading Consumer, class file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/function/Consumer.class)' is broken
[INFO] (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1073)
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.956 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-14T15:37:47+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) on project DataExpo: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I downloaded the scala plugin from online on IntelliJ. My Java version is: "1.8.0_151". Below are the contents of my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dbloads.programs</groupId>
  <artifactId>DataExpo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.7.0</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Could anyone let me know what is the problem here and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're using a deprecated version of the plugin.
try to replace every

```
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
```

by

```
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
```

and remove (the repo no longer exists)

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

and use a more recent version of scala like 2.11 or 2.12

I guess you used a 8 years old template.

see http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/

Comment: Can you tell me which group of tags should I remove and your suggestion ?

Comment: @Sidhartha, I updated my answer, scala-maven-plugin is the successor of maven-scala-plugin since maven 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade jdk version 11 to version 8.